# XSLT - apply one template to children and another to childern of children

Tags: html, xml, templates, xslt, children

I've following structure of xml-file:

```
<root-element>
    <child1>
        Some text
    </child1>
    <child2>
        <grandchild>
            Some text
        </grandchild>
    </child2>
</root-element>
```

My aim is to generate html-output with the aid of a xslt-file. In doing so I want to apply a template to direct children of root element, which outputs the name of the tag as heading 1 and it contents enclosed in <p></p>. As to grandchildern, i want to use almost the same template, but to output their names as heading 2.

To make easier to understand what I want here is sample how HTML-Output would look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Child1</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>

        <h1>Child2</h1>
        <h2>Grandchild</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now my attempt looks like this: http://pastebin.com/wKgSLbcE

But it doesn't work with <xsl:for-each select="./*"> and <xsl:for-each select="././*"> so I want to ask you for help.

Comment: Please edit your markup sample to show well-formed XML. Currently you have a start tag `<child1>` that is not closed at all so it is hard to tell how your input looks and is nested. Then consider to provide a sample of the corresponding HTML you want to create.

Comment: You're right. Now it looks correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to use template matching to achieve your aim, as this is much more in the spirit of XSLT.

For example, to match your 'child' elements, which I guess can be named anything, you could do something like this to match the child elements of the top level element

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*">
   <h1>
      <!-- Output name here -->
   </h1>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Similarly to match grandchildren elements, use this

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
```

As for paragraphs, you would have a template matching the text nodes

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
   <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
   </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output version="4.0" method="html" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" use-character-maps="spaces" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Abschlussarbeit</title>
         </head>
         <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/*/*">
      <h1>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(name(), 1, 1), abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ), substring(name(), 2))"/>
      </h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
      <h2>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(name(), 1, 1), abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ), substring(name(), 2))"/>
      </h2>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()">
      <p>
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
      <title>Abschlussarbeit</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>child1</h1>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <h1>child2</h1>
      <h2>grandchild1</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note, if you are using XSLT 2.0, there is the xpath function "upper-case" you can use to convert the first character of your element name to upper case, rather than using the "translate" method which is used in XSLT 1.0

Comment: I knew it will be simplier than i made it for me. Now i understand xslt a bit better. Thank you!

Comment: btw: how do i check if the selected node is empty? For example: <abstract></abstract> So if there is neither text nor children in between tags i dont want to output anything.

Comment: Try adding the following template `<xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(text())]" />`

Comment: This works fine, but is applied to too much elements. I've several nodes with following structure: <eintrag titel="Title" autor="Author" seite="7" verlag="Publisher" jahr="2013"/>
And i need them to be shown as well, or to be more precise, their attributes.

Comment: Try adding a check for attributes on the empty template match like so: `<xsl:template match="*[not(@*)][not(*)][not(text())]" />`

Comment: You are a great help. I still have to think about how some parts work. But the end result looks already great http://pastebin.com/yA46gQqh If you have any another improvement suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1iPizNL1
I cant figure out how to avoid showing title Literatur if there is no correct element <eintrag> i.e. there is no single <eintrag> with attribute title for example in this case <literatur><eintrag/></literatur>

Comment: It might be best to ask a whole new question, I think. Indeed, this might be preferably to having a long discussion in comments! A new question keeps things nice and tidy, and makes it easier for others to read to the future should they have similiar issues. Thanks!